# Fetch records of 90 days from effective_date (Effective date could be any date)

Tags: teradata

I am trying to fetch records of 90 days prior from effective date. Effective date could be any date. I tried below query, is there any alternative for it. 
        
        `` `select Effective_date-90 as ABC from Table` `` 

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify your question? You say you want to fetch "records" but your query returns only (multiple copies of) a single date. Maybe you want to filter the results `WHERE Effective_date BETWEEN somedatevalue - 90 AND somedatevalue`

Comment: Hi Fred,
Thanks for your reply. My query does not provide single date. I could give an example for easy understanding. For instance we have effective dates as ( 4/1/2008, 5/12/2015, 6/1/2008) when i use my query i get the results as (1/2/2008, 2/11/2015, 3/3/2008). What i am trying to do is i want to use this condition (effective date -90) in where clause. How could i use it.

Comment: You can put the expression in your `WHERE` clause, but it's still unclear exactly what you're trying to get.  Can you post some expected results?

For example, if you want all records with an `effective_date` within the past 90 days, you can use this:

`SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE effective_date > CURRENT_DATE - 90`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for? (let's assume you have a date stamp called date_added)

```
select * from table 
where Date_added between Effective_date-90 and Effective_date;
```